# App does not start when using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I have developed a app using SAPUI5 technology and wanted to deploy in android so used phonegap cordova 2.9.

Earlier i was getting an error call " Class Not Found" , i searched on net and found that i was missing config.xml file in my libs -> xml folder i copied and added the config.xml file and got rid of alert message.

Now the problem is my app does not start. It just shows a blank screen.

Below is the error log which i see in eclipse.

[image: Error]

Can i get any help here.?

Thanks in advance ,
Vishesh.

Comment: It may not be very wise to use Cordova 2.9. Please read http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html

Answer (score 0):

Install cordova plugin required for your project. See the error log, It couldn't find cordova plugin

Comment: hi anupam, Thanks for reply.. Where to find what cordova plugin is needed..? Sorry to ask but this is the first time i am using cordova.

Comment: As you are using 2.9.0 these plugins you will get : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/index.html
You may search for additional plugin (creaated by devs) in google

Comment: But was wondering do i need aditional plugin as i am only doing few jquery to fetch some data..? And i ket the debugger just to see if my code is getting executed but it never hit the debugger

Comment: As I can't see your code, I can not comment on exactly what plugin you needed or exactly what is the reason. But the debugger log clearly shows it is a plugin issue or might be during project creation something happened (worst case)

Comment: After importing to eclipse, right click on project, select properties then open resource panel and delete the 2 excluded item and then apply it, also remember to add jquery library at index.html code (ie. where you have coded) See what happens